# How can I center align menu items? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/

This is code HTML:

```
 <nav class="" role="navigation">
<!--            <div class="container-fluid">-->
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/" rel="home">My Blog</a></h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">

                <!--            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">-->
                <!--                <div class="form-group">-->
                <!--                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">-->
                <!--                </div>-->
                <!--                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>-->
                <!--            </form>-->

                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
                <div class="menu-menu-container"><ul id="menu-menu" class="nav-menu"><li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-29"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=21" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="60" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CLIENTI.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="CLIENTI"><img width="60" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CLIENTI2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="CLIENTI2" style="margin-left: -60px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-6" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=2" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="46" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HOME.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="HOME"><img width="46" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/HOME2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="HOME2" style="margin-left: -46px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=17" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="67" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/AVOCATI.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="AVOCATI"><img width="67" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/AVOCATI2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="AVOCATI2" style="margin-left: -67px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=19" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="186" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA"><img width="186" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="DOMENII-DE-EXPERTIZA2" style="margin-left: -186px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=23" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="78" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ONORARII.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="ONORARII"><img width="78" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ONORARII2.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="ONORARII2" style="margin-left: -78px;"></span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/?page_id=25" class="menu-image-title-hide menu-image-hovered"><span class="menu-image-hover-wrapper"><img width="75" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CONTACT.png" class="menu-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="CONTACT"><img width="75" height="48" src="http://avocat2.dac-proiect.ro/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/CONTACT1.png" class="hovered-image menu-image-title-hide" alt="CONTACT" style="margin-left: -75px;"></span></a></li>
</ul></div>            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
<!--            </div>-->
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

I am new to using bootstrap technology and want to understand how to align the menu items to the center.

I read the Bootstrap documentation but unfortunately I did not understand very well how to solve this problem

How to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
<header id="masthead" class="navbar navbar-default" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="" role="navigation">
<!--            <div class="container-fluid">-->
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse-1">

                <!--            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">-->
                <!--                <div class="form-group">-->
                <!--                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">-->
                <!--                </div>-->
                <!--                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>-->
                <!--            </form>-->

                <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'zdwpbs' ); ?></a>
                <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ,
                                    'menu_class' => 'nav-menu') );
                ?>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
<!--            </div>-->
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</header>
```

I tried this:

```
<script>
  $('.main-menu').addClass('nav-menu text-center'); 
</script>
```

Comment: Your menu is already in the center when i got in your site.

Comment: Sorry...look now at site.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center your menu **ul li** items you should use CSS solution:

```
.nav-menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**text-align: center;** you can use  with *display:* **inline** or **inline- block.**

If you need to align image or text in your li item **too**. Use:

```
.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Perfect Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add text-center on your ul#menu-menu.

**Current:**

```
<ul id="menu-menu" class="nav-menu">
```

**Propsed:**

```
<ul id="menu-menu" class="nav-menu text-center">
```

After it's done:

[image]

Comment: goes very well what you said but I can not find where I can back this change

Comment: class main-menu is generated by a php code. I edited the code to see how it looks

Comment: I don't have your php files. So I can't tell you where to edit. You should find it yourself somehow :) If you using good IDE, editors there must be easy features for find lines.

Comment: Or if you really can't find this line, you can add it via javascript (more brute way). Code is like:     var element = document.getElementById("menu-menu"); element.className += " text-center";